# Five hundred raffle tickets

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Five hundred raffle tickets were sold by a club for a drawing on a prize of 600 dollar. If you buy a raffle ticket for 3$, what can you conclude about the cost of the raffle ticket?

---

*Attempt*: First I calculated the price for all sold tickets $= 3\cdot 500 =1500 $.
Second I subtracted $600$ from $1500 $.
$$1500-600= 900 $$
Is that the cost?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem. Also, what do you mean by "fair"? A raffle expects to make a profit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is difficult to interpret, but the best interpretation I can think of is "what can you say about the production cost of a raffle ticket?"

Let's say that's $\$ x$. $500$ tickets would've cost them $\$500x$ to produce. They sell them for $\$3$ each and then give away a single prize of $\$600$.

The club's profit $P$ in dollars at the end of the venture is:

$P = 1500 - 600 - 500x = 900 - 500x$

To be profitable, $P > 0$, giving $x < \frac 95$.

So the maximum production cost of a single raffle ticket would be $\$1.80$. Beyond this level, the raffle would no longer make sense financially.

Answer (score 0):

$500$ tickets were sold, at a price of $3 per ticket.

This implies that ($3)(500)=$$1500 was made from selling the tickets.

Now, the prize is worth $600, so the organizers of the raffle would be making (1500)-(600)=900 dollars. Ie , 1500 from selling the tickets, and losing 600 from giving the prize.

I am not sure what you mean by the "cost" of the raffle ticket. By your wording, it doesn't really make sense. You said the cost of the raffle ticket was 3 dollars.